# Isosceles trapezoid and cyclic quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Let $ABCD$ and isosceles trapezoid . Let $A_1$  be an arbitrary point on $AC$ , the circumcircle of $\triangle A_1CD$ intersects $BC$ at $B_1$ .Let  $M$ and $N$ be the midpoints of $AC$ and $BC$ respectively ,$A_2$ Is a point on $AC$ such that $A_2M$=$A_1M$ and $B_2$ is a point on $BC$ such that $B_2N$=$B_1N$.
Show that $ABB_2A_2$ is cyclic.

I tried to construct paralelograms in order to handle the midpoint condition but It does not seem to be helpful.

Comment: 1) What is $A_2$? Is it another arbitrary point on AC? 2) Which sides are parallel? Or does that not matter?

Comment: There was a typo, it should be "circumcircle of $A_1CD$"

Comment: Drawing a picture wouldn't kill you. Without any attempts, your post is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $AB \,\, || \,\, CD$, let $E$ and $F$ be the midpoints of segments $AB$ and $CD$ respectively. Then, since the trapezoid $ABCD$ is isosceles with $BC = AD$, the line $EF$ is the line of symmetry of $ABCD$, so that the points $A$ and $B$ are mirror symmetric to each other and the points $C$ and $D$ are mirror-symmetric to each other. Therefore the segments $BC$ and $AD$ are mirror-symmetric to each other.

Let $k_1$ be the circle circumscribed around the triangle $A_1CD$. As a symmetry line, $EF$ is the orthogonal bisector of both segments $AB$ and $CD$, which means that the center of $k_1$ lies on $EF$ and therefore the line $EF$ is a symmetry line of the circle $k_1$ as well, meaning that the circle is mapped to itself under the symmetry in the line $EF$.

Denote by $A^*$ the second point of intersection of the circle $k_1$ with the line $AD$, the first being point $D$. Now, since $BC$ is mapped to $AD$ under the symmetry and the circle $k_1$ is mapped to itself, $BD \cap k_1 = \{B_1, C\}$ is mapped to $AD \cap k_1 = \{A^*, D\}$ which implies that the point $A^*$ is the mirror-symmetric of the point $B_1$ with respect to $EF$. Therefore,
$$AA^* = BB_1 \,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\, AD = BC$$
Since the points $A^*, A_1, C, D$ lie on $k_1$ and $A = DA^* \cap CA_1$, 
$$AA_1 \cdot AC = AA^* \cdot AD = BB_1 \cdot BC$$

The point $A_2$ is the symmetric image of point $A_1$ on the diagonal line $AC$ with respect to the midpoint $M$ of $AC$. Hence, $AA_1 = CA_2$. Analogously, the point $B_2$ is the symmetric image of point $B_1$ on the line $BC$ with respect to the midpoint $N$ of $BC$. Hence, $BB_1 = CB_2$. Then, the identities from above yield
$$CA_2 \cdot CA = AA_1 \cdot AC = BB_1 \cdot BC = CB_1 \cdot CB$$
However the identity $CA_2 \cdot CA = CB_1 \cdot CB$ is possible if and only if the quadrilateral $ABB_2A_2$ is cyclic.